# How do I model a piece of cloth on a chair?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation, collision

I was trying to create something like a piece of cloth hanging on the chair with a cloth and collision simulations, but I couldn't get any results.
Reference photos and my results:

[image]

How would you approach this particular modeling task and what can I do to improve my results?
Thank you in advance[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty basic cloth animation:

So i modeled this perfect chair, took a plane, subdivided it, created two spheres, added collision modifier to the chair and that two spheres, then animated the spheres so i got this nice cloth result like this:

[image]

[image]

Note: yes, you have to tweak some settings in cloth.

Blend file:

[image]

of course you could also use a force field to get this effect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "i got this nice cloth result", this is pretty opinion based, you can not use this kind of expression, you're going to be banned

Comment: i am very sorry. How should i write it, big master guru of Stack exchange, god of Blender and Godfather of modelling? 

Comment: ...and by the way...would be the 4th time if i got locked out...so....‍♂️

Comment: Thanks. I'll try experimenting even more

Comment: Also, "i modeled this perfect chair" is pretty inadequate as well, it's super opinion based, i wouldn't like this kind of chair at home

Comment: @Butyl: if my answer helped you, please click on the checkmark left to my answer

Comment: @moonboots: You are living in Buckingham Palace - that's why you don't like the chair. I have a simple taste ;)

Comment: @moonboots: can you model such a great chair at all!? :D

Comment: actually I did the same but you answered before me  ^^  i get older  :p

Comment: not older. Prettier. Wiser. More experienced. One with the universe.